# Leaving Edit Reasons on your own Questions

Tags: discussion, edits

Should I be leaving edit comments on edits to my own questions?

I find when I'm reviewing, or generally searching for a question; and I happen to edit an answer/question, I always leave an edit comment/reason of what I did, and sometimes why.

But when I edit my own questions, I don't usually leave an edit reason, is this a bad practice? Especially if I have to edit it several times to correct small things, better phrase something, updates from comments and answers, and more details as I debug the issue myself?

Comment: You edit your own questions for editing sake?

Comment: I edit my own question to improve the quality of it, and provide necessary updates/details I might not have known when originally asking, or requested by comments to the question.

Comment: I see a number of reasons specified there. :/

Answer (score 6):

No, its totally your call. On other people's questions, etiquette dictates that you explain your edit, but on your own questions, etiquette will not interfere